# Curl - cannot connect using p12 certificate

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I'm trying to collect some data using `Curl`, connecting to service that some external company provided. They, in addition to address itself, sent me `p12` certificate file that is required to estabilish connection.

When I'm trying to use it with `curl`, I get following error:

```
#58: not supported file type 'P12' for certificate
```

So far I've tried updating curl and php-curl. Nothing changed.

My code:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'cert_path');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'P12');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'my_pass');
...
```

Funny thing is that this code works on our production environment, while it doesn't work on my local machine (Linux Mint 16).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found the solution.

Easiest way to do this is to extract `.pem` key and certificate from `.p12` file.

For example (tested on `linux`):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out file.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
```

Will create key/cert pair in current directory.

Now, to use it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'file.crt.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'file.key.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'pass');
```

Where `pass` is the password from `.p12` file.

Comment: This answer is not fully correct. You dont need 2 separate files. Your commands don't create 'pass' on your files, so they will not be encrypted. Just do 1 file with `-clcerts` option.

Comment: @imclickingmaniac Can you note which command you are saying will work? I'm unclear. Are you saying only the 2nd command is needed? Also, what would then change about the curl_setopt settings? I've tried so many combinations with a .p12 file and password but they all give errors on the ca certs and I just end up here.

Comment: @SteveExdia If I remember correctly this is what you need: `openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts`. This is dummy code to explain how I do it (more or less) using php: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41487980de8fd47316bd8a38a84494e47990024c

Comment: @SteveExdia Here you will find some more information when I had same problems with p12. This is using SOAP, but idea behind this is exact same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918241/curl-soap-request-with-p12-ssl-certificate