# How to use a certificate to access the service

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, tls1.2

I need to send a POST request to the server. The server uses certificates. I have a file with a .p12 extension. This is the first time I come across certificates and do not understand what needs to be done

My code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ''); // ???
var_dump(curl_exec($curl));
var_dump(curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

As a result, I naturally get the error: *bool(false) string(69) "error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: none"*

But I don't know how to get the path to the certificate from the .p12 file

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363317/curl-cannot-connect-using-p12-certificate gives you more info.  Although it's on a slightly different topic.

Comment: Try this [guide](https://curl.se/mail/lib-2005-03/0155.html).